# Debug EXC_BAD_ACCESS on device on Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, opengl, exc-bad-access

I have this dreaded error when I run on the iPhone but not on the simulator. I've tried running instruments for zombies, allocations and sudden terminations but the later will not run on a device. Nothing out of the ordinary is highlighted by these tools. Maybe I'm using them wrongly but its seems pretty straight forward.

Basically I get this error when I've added a 2nd set of data arrays to the app, and on the simulator it uses about 70MB whereas without the 2nd set it uses 20 to 40MB. It really looks like I'm simply out of memory (iPhone 4s) but from what I've read, that's not likely. From the allocations instrument, the last thing that happens is a VM allocation but I don't know if it was successful or anything. The instrument doesn't say anything much at all.

Does anybody have a method for tracking down such a problem with Xcode 6 and running on the device? (My app is using ARC.) Is there a debugger console command I should know?

Thanks

PS: I've also enabled zombie objects in Xcode but also no clues about the error.

Here is the code I was asked to post:

```
//***************************************************/
// Process the constellation lines catalog for OpenGL
//***************************************************/

// Must create a set of polygon objects to be drawn separately
// Each with a vertex and index buffer

NSMutableString *constellationName = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *constellationsTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Do a points and lines scatter plot of the catalog data
int totalVertices = 0;
for (i=0; i<constellationLinesCatalogData.count;) {
    constellationName = [[constellationLinesCatalogData objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:CON_INDEX];
    NSMutableArray *constellation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    while ((i<constellationLinesCatalogData.count) && [[[constellationLinesCatalogData objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:CON_INDEX] isEqualToString:constellationName]) {
        NSMutableArray *constellationVerticesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *constellationIndicesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        while (![[[constellationLinesCatalogData objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:STAR_INDEX] isEqualToString:@""]) {
            cos_ra = cosf(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(
                                                  15*(
                                                      [[[constellationLinesCatalogData objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:RA_INDEX] floatValue]
                                                      )
                                                  ));
            sin_ra = sinf(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(
                                                  15*(
                                                      [[[constellationLinesCatalogData objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:RA_INDEX] floatValue]
                                                      )
                                                  ));
            cos_dec = cosf(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(
                                                   [[[constellationLinesCatalogData objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:DE_INDEX] floatValue]
                                                   ));
            sin_dec = sinf(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(
                                                   [[[constellationLinesCatalogData objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:DE_INDEX] floatValue]
                                                   ));

            NSArray *Position = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:cos_dec*cos_ra],  // X
                                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:cos_dec*sin_ra],  // Y
                                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:sin_dec],         // Z
                                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                                 nil];

            NSArray *Color = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5],
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5],
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5],
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                              nil];

            NSArray *TexCoord0 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                                  nil];

            NSArray *TexCoord1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                                  nil];

            NSArray *Pointsize = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:DEFAULT_POINT_SIZE],
                                  nil];

            NSArray *constellationVertex = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                            Position,
                                            Color,
                                            TexCoord0,
                                            TexCoord1,
                                            Pointsize,
                                            nil];

            [constellationVerticesArray addObject:constellationVertex];
            [constellationIndicesArray addObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithUnsignedInteger:totalVertices]];

            totalVertices++;
            i++;
        }
        NSArray *figure = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                           [[constellationLinesCatalogData objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:CON_INDEX],
                           constellationVerticesArray,
                           constellationIndicesArray,
                           nil];

        [constellation addObject:figure];

        i++;
    }
    [constellationsTemp addObject:constellation];
}
NSArray *constellations = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:constellationsTemp copyItems:YES];

NSLog(@"constellations.count = %lu", (unsigned long)constellations.count);
NSLog(@"totalVertices = %d", totalVertices);

// Setup constellation buffers
Vertex constellationVertices[totalVertices];
GLuint constellationIndices[totalVertices*2];
```

Well, this problem is persisting. There is no info to trace it other than EXC_BAD_ACCESS code 1. The stack trace simply show the setup method as the last call. I thought the problem was in my view controller but after a lot of trial and error, It think it has to be the way it is but maybe there is a subtle problem I can't see. This is my view controller code that calls the setup method which immediately crashes - you probably only need to look at the OpenGL setup at the end:

```
#import "GBStarFieldViewController.h"
#import "GBStarFieldView.h"

#define MOTION_UPDATE_INTERVAL (1/30) // seconds

@interface GBStarFieldViewController ()

@end

@implementation GBStarFieldViewController {

    int i;
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CMMotionManager *motionManager;
    GBStarFieldView *starFieldView;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"GBStarFieldViewController viewDidLoad invoked");

    /****************************/
    // Register for notifications
    /****************************/

    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(tapDetected:)
                   name:@"TapDetected"
                 object:nil];

    [center addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(pinchDetected:)
                   name:@"PinchDetected"
                 object:nil];

    [center addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(oneTouchPanDetected:)
                   name:@"OneTouchPanDetected"
                 object:nil];

    [center addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(twoTouchPanDetected:)
                   name:@"TwoTouchPanDetected"
                 object:nil];

    /****************************************************/
    // Setup location manager
    /****************************************************/

    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] && [CLLocationManager headingAvailable]) {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.headingFilter = kCLHeadingFilterNone;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLHeadingFilterNone;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
        if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
            [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: Failed to get heading services");
    }

    /****************************************************/
    // Setup motion manager
    /****************************************************/

    if ([CMMotionManager availableAttitudeReferenceFrames] & CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical) {
        motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
        [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical];
        motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = MOTION_UPDATE_INTERVAL;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: Failed to get reference frame");
    }

    /*******************/
    // Initialize OpenGL
    /*******************/

    // Create an OpenGL ES context and assign it to the view loaded from storyboard
    starFieldView = (GBStarFieldView *)self.view;
    starFieldView.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    [starFieldView setup];
}
```

Comment: Do you receive any memory warnings? Put a NSLog in those call-backs.

Comment: Do you have a symbolicated crash log you can share?

Comment: Yes, I have NSLog in the memory warning call-backs but none are issued.

Comment: I can't seem to get a crash log as the iPhone does not show up on my devices. Is there a way to get it out of Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Select the view menu, Navigators, Breakpoint navigator (⌘7).

Then click the + at the lower left of the breakpoint navigator column and select "Add Exception Breakpoint". Control-click (or right click) on the resulting breakpoint and change it to break on all Objective-C exceptions.

Then as a final step, right click on the breakpoint again and select Move Breakpoint to>User. This makes the breakpoint global for all of your projects.

Once you've added an exception breakpoint Xcode is more likely to break on the source line of your error. This isn't perfect, but it does make it more likely that you'll see the actual line rather than a line in main.m, which is not useful.

Comment: This is interesting because it IS breaking on a line (    NSLog(@"Processing %lu constellations", (unsigned long)constellations.count);   )
but it appears the bad access is due to the NSArray constellations no longer existing. Looking in the variable window, there are no more objects in constellations that once contained 88 entries, just an empty array - only one object which looks more like a error artifact - with a pointer address. So why has this array, and others it seems been clobbered? That I can't find. If I reduce the size of a previous array creation, the app will run smoothly.

Comment: By the way, if I remove the NSLog line where the failure occurs, it simply occurs a few more lines down in the code.

Comment: Whoa! I just noticed something while going over the variables in the debugger. The 2nd data array I was talking about earlier does not seem to be created! -     Vertex constellationVertices[totalVertices]; - 
After stepping through that line of code, the array does not show up in my variables window and its set to show all. How could that happen?

Comment: If I set a breakpoint just one or two lines farther. Many objects appear to be clobbered. So it seems that allocating this 2nd data array is causing the problem. But if instead, I single step through the array allocation all the way the NSLog line, the objects appear intact but I still get the bad access error.

Comment: Post the bit of your header file where you declare constellations. Then post the code where you create the array. My guess is that you declared it as weak, and it's being deallocated and set to nil.

Comment: I posted the code where everything is taking place. Initially constellations is built in  a mutable array and then copied to a non-mutable for efficiency later. At the end where I try to declare constellationVertices, things start to go wrong.

Comment: Stepping back from your fun with NSArrays for a minute... Don't use NSArrays and NSNumber to represent openGL structures. It takes more memory, it's slower, and you just end up having to convert back to C data structures before passing them to OpenGL. Learn how to create the C data structures. That's what OpenGL uses, and if you're not comfortable with C structs, malloc, pointers, and the like, you are not ready for OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was using NS types because I thought it would be easier to handle them when building the constellations database but I'll try using the C types.

Comment: Well, I recoded the generation of constellations vertex and index arrays using C arrays written directly as I read the constellations file data. Works but still get EXC_BAD_ACCESS so I moved the creation of the vertex and index arrays all the way to the beginning of the -setup() method -using fixed sizes- and now the crash is as soon as setup is called from the view controller. Again, there is no problem in the simulator. I read somewhere that there was an issue with either location manager or motion manager killing the app on the device but not the simulator.

Comment: Post your code along with info on the line that's crashing and the specific error message and stack trace.

Comment: I found the problem. I was setting up the EAGLContext in the view controller. This was a remnant from a tutorial (that was oversimplified it seems).

Comment: Aside from the crash from your tutorial remnant, the takeaway is to use C data structures when doing OpenGL. It's much, MUCH more efficient since that is the native format for OpenGL. For that matter, in any case where you're manipulating thousands of scalar values, you're usually better off with structs and C arrays rather than Objective C container objects and NSNumbers.